# Catch a focus lost event in a web forms textbox?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, focus

How can I "listen" for the focus lost event of a textbox in a .NET web form? Is the only way using OnBlur in combination with JavaScript?

Thanks :-)

Comment: You can only catch the event on javascript.Blur event is the only way actually.

Answer (score 0):

> "Is the only way using OnBlur in
>   combination with JavaScript?"

**Yes**

If the Text was changed you can also use the [TextChanged](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCcQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx&ei=5SvRTJrgCYne4gaahaHODA&usg=AFQjCNE350Vx0Ztqqsihsf2NkTr1FXFpcw&sig2=3wRgxfmfQ1u1_jzma27WuQ)-event(when AutoPostBack="True").

[This SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310902/asp-net-textbox-lostfocus-event) describes how to customize a Textbox to raise a FocusLost-Event on serverside.