# Server side on lost focus event for a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, textbox, focus, server-side

How can i fire a server side on lost focus event for a textbox without triggering a javascript function i want it server side function is it possible ?

```
<asp:TextBox id="Example" runat="server" />
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Without a page postback?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is AJAX, (or UpdatePanel in asp.net web form control, which seems to be using by you instead of MVC). This involves javascript but still it involves the server side event.
Or you need to write some code overriding the TextBox event, it did involve javascript just that you don't call it explicitly on the page. Like this [ASP.NET TextBox LostFocus event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310902/asp-net-textbox-lostfocus-event)